# Why is my flutter Future<String> async function returning a null string?

Tags: flutter

```
 Future<String> upload_to_server(File image) async {
    var file;
    String str;
    String filename = image.path.split('/').last;
    FormData formData = new FormData();
    file = await MultipartFile.fromFile(image.path,
        filename: filename, contentType: MediaType('image', 'jpeg'));
    formData.files.add(MapEntry('photo', file));

      Response response =
          await Dio().post("http://10.0.2.2:5000/", data: formData);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) str = jsonDecode(response.data.toString());

    print(str);
    return str;
  }
```

This function is returning a null string however when I print the value of the string I am getting a non null string output. I believe the problem might be with json decoding. Could somebody help me figure this out?

Comment: can you try printing `response.data` do you find any data there?

Comment: Yes I tried printing response.data as per your suggestion and nothing is getting printed However the caption I am trying to generate from the flask code is printing successfully

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I discovered that I was getting a null output because I had forgotten to include a particular file now having done that I get the following output:{caption:  dog is running through the grass }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With dio you do not have to use jsonDecode, response.data should give you the string.

```
str = response.data;
```

Comment: correct Thanks after doing so I got the output as {caption: dog is running through the grass } and I used str['caption'] to get the caption

Answer (score 0):

> the problem is occurred because you try to decode response.data

```
Future<String> upload_to_server(File image) async {
var file;
String str;
String filename = image.path.split('/').last;
FormData formData = new FormData();
file = await MultipartFile.fromFile(image.path,
    filename: filename, contentType: MediaType('image', 'jpeg'));
formData.files.add(MapEntry('photo', file));

  Response response =
      await Dio().post("http://10.0.2.2:5000/", data: formData);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  str = response.data.toString();

print(str);
return str;
    }else{
throw Expression('Failed to Load Response');
        }
```

Comment: I tried printing using this but now I am getting ``` {caption:  dog is running through the grass }``` as the output isn't this Json only

Comment: because your server send response in json. when you use toString, it converted in strong

Answer (score 0):

Try this way if you want to decode:

```
dynamic str = jsonDecode(jsonEncode(response.data));
```

hope this work's

Comment: Tried this and got the output as: {caption: dog is running through the grass } , isn't it still json though?

Comment: So just do this jsonEncode(response.data) or json.encode(response.data)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
 var data = json.decode(json.encode(response.data));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).